# About ssh configuration file internal "~" symbol parsing problem

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh

SEE: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76844392/about-ssh-configuration-file-internal-symbol-parsing-problem

1. I use the root account to log in to the system  (`HOME`: **/root**)
2. I executed a script file (source script)
3. In script file, I changed the value of the environment variable `HOME`   (`HOME`: **/another**)
4. I use `~`(**$HOME**) in my SSH profile (**~/.ssh/config**)
5. `SSH -T git@github.com` shows that ssh is still using the original default values   (`HOME`: **/root**)

May I ask why? (The `HOME` I expect SSH to work with should be: **/another**)
How can I solve this problem?

**~/.ssh/config**：

```
Host gh github.com
    User git
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    HostName github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I can be sure that the source script is working properly because the configuration file is found correctly through **~/.ssh/config**(**/another/.ssh/config**);; Only **~**(**%d**) in the configuration file is not effective, or the previous value(**/root**);

Comment: SSH doesn't use the `HOME` environment variable. It asks the system (usually eventually reading `/etc/passwd`, but could also be getting the details from LDAP, etc.) for the executing user's details.